# insertNewObjectForEntityForName returns nil

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, insert

I've been using Core Data since it was released for iOS, but I'm having trouble figuring out what's going on with an insertNewObjectForEntityForName method invocation for one of my entities.  When the method is called it simply returns a *nil* object and does not throw an exception.

Here's the code:

```
@try {
    self.observation = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Observation" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    NSLog(@"No exception on insert");
}
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Insert exception - %@", exception.description);
}
NSLog(@"observation: %@", self.observation ? self.observation.description : @"nil");
```

and here's the output:

```
2012-10-19 10:16:08.749 Track[63779:c07] No exception on insert
2012-10-19 10:16:08.750 Track[63779:c07] observation: nil
```

I can perform the insert on all the other entities in my ERD.  It's just this one that's mocking (*pun intended*) me.

Comment: No idea if it will tell you anything but....  Assuming nothing along the path is nil, you should be able to use `moc.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel` to get a list of entity names as a sanity check using something like `NSLog(@"Entities: %@", [[moc.persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectModel entitiesByName] allKeys]);`.

Comment: Don't see any error, unless you overwrote -description to return @"nil" in some or all cases - which I would doubt.... :) ps, what if you log the observation.description in the try block?

Comment: @PhillipMills – I'd tried that and it is in the list of tables.

Comment: @RM34545 Having the same issue as you. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

(Xcode 7.2 Swift project) After renaming an entity, my data model got confused and began returning nil objects when performing `insertNewObjectForEntityForName`. Here are the three things I did to fix this:

1. I first used @PhillipMills' suggestion:`po mainQueueContext.persistentStoreCoordinator?.managedObjectModel`
   and in the output I saw that the "managedObjectClassName" was the old entity/class name with the project prefixed.

   > ... NewEntityName = "(< NSEntityDescription: 0x7f9773783440>) name DetectedData, managedObjectClassName MyProject.OldEntityName, ...
2. To try to resolve this, I deleted and recreated the entity. But this also returned nil objects when inserting. I looked in interface builder and saw that the Class field was blank. I set the class name to resolve this.
   [image: Xcode Data Model Inspector]
3. At some point during this process the Xcode generated Swift files had a third issue:

missing objc() declaration:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class NewEntityName: NSManagedObject {
    // Insert code here to add functionality to your managed object subclass
}
```

Fixed Version:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(NewEntityName) //THIS WAS MISSING
class NewEntityName: NSManagedObject {
    // Insert code here to add functionality to your managed object subclass
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't see any error, unless you overwrote -description to return @"nil" in some or all cases - which I would doubt.... :) ps, what if you log the observation.description in the try block?

**edit**
Posted this comment as answer so you can accept. Wouldn't logging a nil object print out (null)? so you must, in fact, be logging literally @"nil" in the NSManagedObject's description method. No? ;)

Alternatively, could it be some faulting problem? Log different literals in the ternary clause instead of .description (log @"Yes" : @"No") to check if it is a property problem.

Comment: No the *description* method is not printing **nil**.

If I change the ternary clause to: NSLog(@"observation: %@", self.observation ? @"not nil" : @"nil");

The output is still:
2012-10-20 18:12:45.257 Track[67079:c07] observation: nil

Comment: Okay, then tell us what self.observation looks like (the property)

Comment: self.observation is an instance of the entity/table/class named Observation that aggregates eight properties.